# How do I restrict access to certain groups for an entire controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I understand I can use decorators and filters, but then wouldn't I have to specify at the top of every ActionResult?  Need something of a blanket approach to the entire controller.

Comment: Filters can be specified at the top of the controller, and will apply to the entire controller

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [AuthorizeAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute.aspx) on the controller:

> When you mark an action method with AuthorizeAttribute, access to that action method is restricted to users who are both authenticated and authorized. If you mark a controller with the attribute, all action methods in the controller are restricted.

Comment: Just verified putting [Authorize(Roles="roleToAuthorize")] above Controller and works as expected.  Thank you!